# I can't move any element in the constraint layout through the design Tap, I can't move the item and drag it, what is the problem?

Tags: android-studio, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

As you see in the image I am trying to set the constraints of the `TextView` but I can't in the Android Studio Design mode.

[image: As you see in the image I am trying to set the constraints of the text view but I can't]

Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: remove the four  constraints of your element and move it...

Answer (score 0):

Change your settings to code view.[image]